# Unable to install linecache19 gem on ruby193

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I know this is one of the problem everybody is having these days and many of them have found ways to troubleshoot this problem. Unfortunately I have tried all the solutions but none of them seem to work on my system.

when I do

```
gem install linecache19
```

I get this error, as below

```
gem install linecache19
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR:  Error installing linecache19:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby_core_source-0.1.5/lib/ruby_core_source.
rb:39: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for vm_core.h... yes
checking for version.h... yes
creating Makefile


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache
19-0.5.13 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/linecache19-0.5.13/ext/tra
ce_nums/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [debugger-linecache](https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger-linecache), it's just an updated working fork of linecache19. You won't have installation issues like the one you are having because it's not built as a C extension anymore, it's 100% ruby.

```
gem install debugger-linecache
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you mate..It worked but looks like installing ruby-debug-base19x gem for Rubymines is a pain.

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11074794/cant-install-ruby-debug-base19x-gem#11075890 Good luck!