# Rubymine 6.0.2, unable to debug

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rubymine, ruby-debug

On my new OSX Mavericks install, I wanted to give Rubymine a try and just can't get the debugger working (although i managed to get it working on Windows 7 with IntelliJ and the ruby plugin).

Here's what I did (XCode and commandline tools already installed):

```
homebrew install ruby
gem update --system
```

Then I installed Rubymine and opened some of my projects. Upon starting the debugger, rubymine tries to install dependencies:

> Failed to Install Gems. Following gems were not installed:
>   /Applications/RubyMine.app/rb/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22.gem: Error
>   installing ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22.gem: ERROR: Failed to build gem
>   native extension.
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
>   mkrf_conf.rb Installing base gem You don't have write permissions for
>   the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:620:in
>   `verify_gem_home'
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:740:in`
>   pre_install_checks'
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:213:in `install'
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:136:in`block in
>   install' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:120:in
>   `each' /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:120:in`
>   install'
>   /Library/Ruby/Site/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:389:in
>   `install' mkrf_conf.rb:34:in`rescue in  ' mkrf_conf.rb:27:in ` ' rake
>   failed, exit code 1 Gem files will remain installed in /Volumes/OSX
>   DATA/Users/freakazoid/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22 for
>   inspection. Results logged to /Volumes/OSX
>   DATA/Users/freakazoid/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/gem_make.out
>   /Applications/RubyMine.app/rb/gems/debase-0.0.9.gem: Error installing
>   debase-0.0.9.gem: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb
>   /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby:
>   invalid option -D (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError) extconf
>   failed, exit code 1 Gem files will remain installed in /Volumes/OSX
>   DATA/Users/freakazoid/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/debase-0.0.9 for
>   inspection. Results logged to /Volumes/OSX
>   DATA/Users/freakazoid/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/debase-0.0.9/gem_make.out

I can without problems do a

```
gem install debugger
```

on my osx terminal

Any help out there?

Comment: run `which ruby` and post output. Also are you using anything like RVM to manage ruby installations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Beartech, you pointed me to the right direction: 
Rubymine was looking for ruby in "/Library/..../ruby" and homebrew of course had ruby installed to another location. I had to edit my rubymine settings and point the ruby sdk to homebrew's ruby. Then i had to restart rubymine in order to successfully use the new sdk location. (I had previousl not restartet rubymine ...)

Answer (score 8):

You need to get the source files since they aren't included.

```
gem install debugger-ruby_core_source
```

Then try again.

Also, since I've found this sometimes isn't set correctly in Rubymine, in the menu bar go to "Rubymine" -> "preferences" -> "Ruby SDK and Gems" and make sure it is pointed to the version of Ruby you are expecting.

Comment: I encountered a RubyMine bug when changing Ruby version. When I changed, I noticed the language level is 1.8 when I switched to 2.2, and this prevents debugging from using the correct tools. Hope this gives insight to people who are struggling with debugger.