# Failing to install ruby-debug-ide gem under ruby 2.1.2

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install the ruby-debug-ide gem under ruby 2.1.2 . This to debug in Rubymine.

It worked for ruby1.9.3 but not for this version.
here is the error:

```
1.3.5/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.1.2-p95/***internal.h:209: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘x’***
```

Here is the output.

I would love the ability to make sence or debug this in some way . A quick fix will also be great by the way :-)

```
Fetching: ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22.gem (100%)
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb
    Installing base gem
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/ruby extconf.rb
    checking for vm_core.h... no
    checking for vm_core.h... no
    checking for vm_core.h... yes
    creating Makefile

    make "DESTDIR=" clean

    make "DESTDIR="
    compiling breakpoint.c
    compiling context.c
    compiling debase_internals.c
    In file included from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@v1_v2/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.5/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.1.2-p95/method.h:14,
                     from /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@v1_v2/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.5/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.1.2-p95/vm_core.h:24,
                     from ./hacks.h:1,
                     from debase_internals.c:2:
    /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@v1_v2/gems/debugger-ruby_core_source-1.3.5/lib/debugger/ruby_core_source/ruby-2.1.2-p95/***internal.h:209: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘x’***
    make: *** [debase_internals.o] Error 1

    make failed, exit code 2

    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@v1_v2/gems/debase-0.0.9 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@v1_v2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/debase-0.0.9/gem_make.out
    /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:51:in `block in make'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `each'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:43:in `make'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:47:in `block in build'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:677:in `build_extensions'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:232:in `install'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:142:in `block in install'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:126:in `each'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:126:in `install'
      /Users/ohad/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:389:in `install'
      mkrf_conf.rb:34:in `rescue in <main>'
      mkrf_conf.rb:27:in `<main>'

    rake failed, exit code 1

    Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@v1_v2/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22 for inspection.
    Results logged to /Users/ohad/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@v1_v2/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.1.0-static/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/gem_make.out
```

Also, I failed to install with ruby  `rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.2 --disable-binary` with this error

```
`dyld: Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/openssl/1.0.1i/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
  Reason: image not found
Failed reading certificates path for '/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl' with return code: ().
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
or visit https://rvm,, for more information.
Requirements installation failed with status: 133.`
```

Comment: I’ve had no problem installing it with Ruby 2.1.1 on Debian Jessie/Testing. From the captial “U” in Users I’m guessing you’re on OS X. Beware that some gems in OS X are tricky to install (e.g. Nokogiri). What OS X version are you running? If you’re using RVM, try Ruby 2.1.1 and start with a clean gemset wit `rvm gemset use --create debug_ide` and try again. I’ll have a look later in my Mac to see if it also fails.

Comment: I’ve successfully installed it on Ruby 2.1.2p95 (again in Debian).

Comment: Check this question, it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055685/rubymine-6-0-2-unable-to-debug

Comment: It installs without a hitch in OS X Mavericks, Ruby 2.1.2p95 and a clean gemset. It’s definitely something in your environment.

Comment: hi @Alf, thanks for the replay. I am using OSx 10.9.4. tried the fresh gemset and t didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using Homebrew, Macports...?

Comment: Homebrew. but not for install the gems.

Comment: I think I realized what your problem is. I posted an answer below.

Comment: I updated my previous answer based on your output (missing OpenSSL libraries). Read the additional info to see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the gem `debugger-ruby_core_source` can’t find the header file `vm_core.h`, which is part of Ruby’s source code. To install the source only (given that you have the binaries installed already) do:

```
$ rvm fetch ruby-2.1.2
```

You can also reinstall from source (a bit slower but it’s a good habit):

```
$ rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.2 --disable-binary
```

---

**Update based on your additional error message**

According to your message, you need to install OpenSSL:

```
$ brew install openssl
```

To sum up:

1. You can’t install `debugger-ruby_core_source` because it needs the
   Ruby source for your Ruby version.
2. You can’t install the Ruby source
   code with RVM because the Open SSL libraries are missing.

To remedy that type `rvm autolibs homebrew` so that RVM will install the missing packages if needed (you might need root permissions and enter your password when requested). This also lets RVM takes care of dependency problems from now on, you shouldn’t need to type the command again.

Comment: hi @alf, didnt work unfourtuntly. added the output in the question

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, and installing the `debugger-ruby_core_source` gem manually before installing `ruby-debug-ide` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me today, and solved it after running `brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force`

Hope it helps.